# Properties not changing on NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an `NSOperation` running on a background thread, and I want to change a property of it, a float named `runSpeed`, upon getting a memory warning on the main thread. The next time the background thread hits runSpeed though, it appears to be the same value it was previously.

How can I make sure it changes in the `NSOperation` thread when i change it on the main thread?

EDIT:

Didn't post code originally because I assumed I was thinking about it wrong. Here's my code:

**AppDelegate**

```
-(void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"memory warning");
    if (dataUpdateIsActive) {
        NSLog(@"data update is active");
        dataUpdate.runSpeed = 10;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(resetRunSpeed)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Then in a method:

```
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    dataUpdate = [[JDataUpdate alloc] init];

    [dataUpdate setOldPSC:[oldContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    [dataUpdate setCurrentPSC:[newContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    [dataUpdate setRunSpeed:0.5];
    [dataUpdate setEntriesToCreate:250];
    [dataUpdate setSaveFrequency:10];

    dataUpdateIsActive = YES;
    [operationQueue addOperation:dataUpdate];
```

Both of those `NSLogs` get triggered.

**NSOperation**

```
- (void)main
{
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [self entriesToCreate]; ++index) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[self runSpeed]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some code :) Usually, this should 'just work'.

Comment: @deanWombourne Updated with code.

Comment: in the for loop log runSpeed, as well as when you change it in applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning.

Comment: @DavidH Alright, the line after I change it, I put in a NSLog and the result was '0'. Every NSLog after it's called in the NSOperation returns 0.5.

Comment: That doesnt make sense. You set the operation's value, then read it back from where you set it, its 0? The original value should be some big number - say 2. Then you should be seeing a string of '2's coming out. Set the value in your controller to 1, Log that you did that, then read it back from the operation and verify its 1 and log that. The next time the operation runloop runs, it should be 1 - you should see that.

Comment: @DavidH Yes, it logs 0.5 every time. Then below where it is set, it says it's set to 0.

Comment: Right - but did you read back the value you set - to see that in fact its the new value and not '0'? The property on the NSOperation subclass should be atomic, not 'nonatomic', since you are setting on a different thread.

Comment: Also, note that if your reference to the operation gets set to nil, then NSLog(@"FLOAT=%f", operation.myFloat) will return 0 too.